# Once in a lifetime

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Is there a way to enforce the number of executions of a member function to one? To explain, lets say I have

```
class foo {
public:
    void Once();
};
```

I want **every instance of foo to call the member function foo::Once() exactly one time**. If a call has been made, to prohibit calling again, and if no call has been made, then call before destruction.

- Is there an idiom or design pattern related to this?
- Is the hard coded solution of placing a `foo::was_called_flag` member (which I would set to 0 or 1) acceptable or are there vulnerabilities to consider??
- Is there a solution that scales nicely to arbitrary number of executions

Comment: use a counter.  what do you want to happen when the caller violates your rules?

Comment: ...a constructor gets called once...

Comment: @doctorlove But sometimes doing computations in a constructor is just not appropriate.

Comment: instead you can restrict at a place where function called.

Comment: I would simply use [`std::call_once`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) with a flag per instance.

Comment: Please open this question the subject is very interesting, especially if someone can state a solution that will take multi-threading into account.

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, there is no prebuilt solution for this. However, it is simple enough to write it yourself. Here are the points that you need to consider:

1. A flag/counter is fine. However, if you have concurrent access to your object, you should use a flag/counter of type `std::atomic<>`. Don't use a lock, it's complete overkill.
2. You need a check of the flag/counter in the function, as you described.
3. You also need to insert a call to the function into your destructor. As with all destructors, it should be virtual. However, be aware that, if the object is of some subclass of your class, all subclass destructors will have been run before your destructor gets a chance to call `Once()`. Thus, you might be calling `Once()` on a disfunctional object.
4. If you have to ensure that `Once()` is run before possible subclasses are destructed, you must move the call from the destructor into a `finalize()` method that sets another flag, and assert on that flag in your destructor.

Comment: That was very thorough, thnx!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an idiom or design pattern related to this?

```
class Foo {
    bool once_called;
  public:
    void once()
    {
        if (once_called)
            throw TwiceError();
        once_called = true;
    }
};
```

> are there vulnerabilities to consider?

There's a potential race condition where two threads try to call `once` on the same object at the same time.

> Is there a solution that scales nicely to arbitrary number of executions

A counter, initially `n`. Decrement the counter in the member function and make the call fail when the counter reaches zero.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the counter approach is the best way I can think of. You should just make sure you scale it properly in a multithreaded scenario,i.e. to protect the counter from data races:

```
#include<mutex>

class foo {
public:
    foo() : counter (0) {}

    const static int CALL_LIMIT = 1;

    void Once()
    {
        mtx.lock();
        counter++;
        if (counter>CALL_LIMIT)
        {
            mtx.unlock();
            return; /* or throw an error */
        } 
        mtx.unlock();
        /* Rest of the code */
    }

private:
    static std::mutex mtx;
    int counter;

};
```

And of course you should consider calling Once() in destructor as well.

Comment: Your usage of the mutex is incorrect, it's left locked when you do the early return! You can easily avoid such errors by either using `std::lock_guard`, or lock-free types (`std::atomic<>`).

Comment: @cmaster Thanks, I also first considered using lock-free types, but then, is there an atomic test and set operation in STL for ints (there is one for boolean, but I am not aware of a TAS for other types)?

Comment: You can simply use the increment operator, as in `if(++counter > CALL_LIMIT)`, it is guaranteed to be atomic if `counter` is an `atomic<>` type, and it is perfectly equivalent to your code.

Comment: It is not about being atomic, it is about the fact that operator++ usually returns a reference, thus a context switch after ++ execution and before > operator can be unsafe.

PS: here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith I just read  that operator++ on atomic types returns a copy of the stored value. So you are right, your implementation is equivalent to mine.

Comment: From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith : "Unlike most pre-increment and pre-decrement operators, the pre-increment and pre-decrement operators for atomic types do not return a reference to the modified object. They return a copy of the stored value instead."

Answer (score 0):

I assume you always can create a naive solution, like (more an algorithm than a C++ code):

```
class foo {
   static std::vector<foo*> callers;

   void Once()
   {
       if(std::find(callers.begin(), callers.end(), this)!=callers.end())
       {
           // do stuff ...
           callers.push_back(this);
       }   
   }
```

obviously, you can have a `std::map<foo*, int>` if you need to be able to control how many times you want to allow the callers to call and modify the code accordingly.

Addressing the "no call has been made, then call before destruction" (not sure if I understood it correctly) you can simply call `Once()` from the destructor, this would solve the problem.

And of course, another problem comes up: what if the OS thinks that it is a wise decision to create an element at the same location as an already deleted one ... To avoid this, at the end of the destructor, or at the beginning of the constructor you should remove the `this` from the static vector/map.

Comment: This is horribly inefficient. It's O(n^2), where n is the number of `foo` objects that are alive. Just imagine you have a million `foo` objects; do you really want to search the entire list every time two times for each object (once inside `Once()`, and once inside the destructor of `foo` to remove it from the list again).

Comment: The O can be improved by simply using a set (or an ordered vector and binary search for insertion and ... search), it was very original to implement such a 'logging'/'check in-check out' solution in this context. Sadly my +1 went lost due to downvotes

Comment: @cmaster that is true, however this approach will allow you to later decouple the check from the class itself, and make a more generic handler which will be able to take all kind of objects for all kind of methods, without to have to include this information in  the class itself.

Comment: @fritzone With this attitude, you will never be able to create such fast and powerful software as linux or git. I'm sure glad not all developers share your view, because performance *is* a feature, and an important one in many cases.